# How to debug ignored exception in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I got a lot of ignored exceptions when my (python 2.7) program exits. But since the project scale is large, and based on a project developed by others, it's hard to locate the bug with such info. Is there any way to get the exception trace, or any other methods that can help? Thanks.

```
Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in <object repr() failed> ignored
Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in <object repr() failed> ignored
Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in <object repr() failed> ignored
...
Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in <object repr() failed> ignored
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run:

```
$ python -v your_file.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I would scan the codebase for strings that match the output.  Something like `Exception .* ignored` as the exception and object information are likely to be formatting variables.  This should find the statements that generate the output.

Once you have found these statements, assuming that they are inside a try / except block you can use the tools in the [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) module to print the tracebacks, or, if the [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) package is being used, pass the keyword argument `exc_info=True` to the log [method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug).

It's also  worth scanning to see if [sys.excepthook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) is being overridden.